# How to safely get the return value of setjmp

Tags: c, setjmp

I would like to return an error code using longjmp, and pass it on from the  function that called setjmp. Simplified code:

```
int do_things(stuff ........)
{
 int error_code;
 jmp_buf jb;

 if ((error_code = setjmp(jb)) == 0) {
    /* do stuff */
    return 0;
 }
 else {
    return error_code;
 }
}
```

But I'v read:
 "An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts:"

```
 the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement

if (setjmp(jb)) {
switch (setjmp(jb)) {
while (setjmp(jb)) {
```

or

```
 one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand
 an integer constant expression, with the resulting expression being
 the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement

if (setjmp(jb) < 3) {
```

or

```
 the operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting
 expression being the entire controlling expression of a
 selection or iteration statement

if (!setjmp(jb)) {
```

or

```
 the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).

setjmp(bf);
```

Is there a nice way get the return value?
( without using `switch`, and writing a `case` for all possibly values )

**EDIT**

Thanks to Matt for finding it in the c99 rationale.
What I came up with now, is:

```
int do_things(stuff ........)
{
  volatile error_code;
  jmp_buf jb;

  if (setjmp(jb) == 0) {
     working_some(&error_code, ....);
     working_again(&error_code, ....);
     working_more(&error_code, ....);
     working_for_fun(&error_code, ....);
     return 0;
  }
  else {
     general_cleanup();
     return error_code;
  }
}
```

One more variable, doesn't seem very nice...

Comment: if that's all true, then it's clear that the whole point of listing all the possibilities is to let you know that you cannot store the return value... so you already know the answer.

Comment: Sad, that makes it almost pointless. I would like to do only a general clean-up, and pass an error_code to another comilation unit, and surely don't want to longjmp to another compilation unit. Noone before me met this problem?? Am I doing something totally wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf):

> One proposed requirement on setjmp is that it be usable like any other function, that is, that it 
>   be callable in any expression context, and that the expression evaluate correctly whether the 
>   return from setjmp is direct or via a call to longjmp. Unfortunately, any implementation of 
>   setjmp as a conventional called function cannot know enough about the calling environment to 
>   save any temporary registers or dynamic stack locations used part way through an expression evaluation. (A setjmp macro seems to help only if it expands to inline assembly code or a call 
>   to a special built-in function.) The temporaries may be correct on the initial call to setjmp, but 
>   are not likely to be on any return initiated by a corresponding call to longjmp. These 
>   considerations dictated the constraint that setjmp be called only from within fairly simple 
>   expressions, ones not likely to need temporary storage.
>
> An alternative proposal considered by the C89 Committee was to require that implementations 
>   recognize that calling setjmp is a special case, and hence that they take whatever precautions 
>   are necessary to restore the setjmp environment properly upon a longjmp call. This proposal 
>   was rejected on grounds of consistency: implementations are currently allowed to implement 
>    library functions specially, but no other situations *require* special treatment.

My interpretation of this is that it was considered to be too restrictive to specify that `a = setjmp(jb);` must work. So the Standard leaves it undefined.  But a particular compiler may choose to support this (and hopefully, would document it). To be portable, I guess you should use some preprocessor checks to verify that the code is being compiled with a compiler that is known to support this.

Comment: I wish the Standard would define macros to indicate whether compilers support constructs which many compilers could support without difficulty but some cannot, and define a term for the "compliance" of a program which requires features that implementations are not required to support, but only uses them on implementations that support them (and may refuse compilation on those that don't).  IMHO, that would be more useful than the present term "strictly compliant" which many kinds of code cannot realistically hope to meet.

Answer (score 0):

[POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html) indeed specifies these limitations. However, on Linux, [`setjmp(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) doesn't mention them, so on that platform you can simply do:

```
int retval = setjmp(jb);
```

Of course this comes at the cost of some portability, but I don't know how bad it is.

Comment: I'v read it in C99 . Also found this using Google: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/setjmp.html

Comment: I will just edit the question to mention C99 . I would like this to be ok even on Windows, or future versions of windows and GNU and whatever.

Comment: have you checked C11?

Comment: I'v checked it now, no luck, found the same under 7.31.1.

Comment: This is very wrong. The "return" value by setjmp() cannot be used in an assignment (or initialiser), only in a test (if() or switch() )

Comment: Don't trust on linux's documentation, assigning the "return" from setjmp() is just against the standard, and generally unsafe. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c/q3aXSO2yaZw/Uq4C8sR5fKgJ for an in-depth discussion.